# Custom editable field in Woocommerce admin edit order pages into each item

Tags: woocommerce

I have a field "file_url" defined by code for every order item. But i must have to insert also this meta field editable in the backend order page. I can have also another input field into each order item line, i just need an input field to save this data for each order item line.

Comment: You don't need anything as Woocommerce handle already that on orders that have an **editable** status (which are "on hold" or "pending" status).

Comment: I should insert data when order is complete : users buy a service and then customer create a file and set field as file url. I founded a way creating a custom post type, having order number and item number and a meta field for that data, and updating wc order with that data, when saving post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woocommerce checks if order is editable or not and it does not allow to edit orders that are processing or completed. But there is a hook to change this. You can simply add this code to functions.php in your theme folder:

```
function make_orders_editable( $is_editable, $order ) {
    // Allow only for admin and moderators
    if ( current_user_can( "manage_options" ) ) {
        return true;
    }
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_is_editable', 'make_orders_editable', 10, 2 );
```

But be careful - this will allow to edit ALL data in orders for admin user and moderators.